# Matching multiple optional characters depending on each other

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all valid prefixes of `substitute` followed by other characters, so that

- `sub/abc/def` matches the `sub` part.
- `substitute/abc/def` matches the `substitute` part.
- `subt/abc/def` either doesn't match or only matches the `sub` part, not the `t`.

My current Regex is `/^s(u(b(s(t(i(t(u(te?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?/`, which works, however this seems a bit verbose.

Is there any better (as in, less verbose) way to do this?

Comment: use alternation operator.

Comment: @AvinashRaj How? `s|su|sub|subs|subst|substi|subtsit|substitu|substitut|substitute` is the only thing I can think of and seems even more verbose to me.

Comment: `^s(?:ubstitute|ubstitut|ubstitu|ubstit|ubsti|ubst|ubs|ub|u)?` there is a difference between yours and mine.

Comment: You answered your own question.

Comment: @JLILIAmen no, it won't.

Comment: What are you referring to by *it*? @AvinashRaj

Comment: @JLILIAmen see https://regex101.com/r/zE3iK5/5

Comment: @RickHitchcock he wants to match only a particular part, not the whole string.

Comment: @RickHitchcock op edited his question. He also wants to match only the `sub` in `subt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a two-step regex

1. find first word of subject by using this simple pattern `^(\w+)`
2. use the extracted word from step 1 as your regex pattern e.g. `^subs` against the word `substitute`

Comment: Unless someone comes up with a Regex, I think this is the way to go. I think Regex would be a bit overkill for 2. though, something like string.indexOf() should be enough.

Comment: but `subt` won't match `substitute`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, it is based on the original post `subt/abc/def doesn't match.` but you're right.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't really clear about this. It doesn't really matter whether it matches or not in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This would do like the same as you mentioned in your question.

```
^s(?:ubstitute|ubstitut|ubstitu|ubstit|ubsti|ubst|ubs|ub|u)?
```

The above regex will always try to match the large possible word. So at first it checks for `substitute`, if it finds any then it will do matching else it jumps to next pattern ie, `substitut` , likewise it goes on upto `u`.

[DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/zE3iK5/3) [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/zE3iK5/4)

Comment: Yes, but it is almost double the character count.

Comment: @jazzpi i just provided an alternative. It could be easy for us to write the regex like mine but yours is so hard which contains many capturing groups, many optional quantifier `?`.. further you could reduce `ub|u` to `ub?`